# Why retag from infection to contamination?

Tags: discussion

Retagged question are about (possible) infections. If these tags are really the same, shouldn't they be made synonyms?  If they are not, why was [Consequences of infection in a beer?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/q/302/12577) edited?

Answer (score 3):

Beer cannot become infected, only living organisms can become infected. Beer becomes contaminated with a biological entity.

The yeast in your beer/cider/wine could become infected, with a virus; but your beer can never become infected only contaminated.

Strictly speaking we should not have an infection tag, and only have the contamination tag.

Comment: This does not answer my question about edits instead of making tag synonyms. Also, it only shows your edits was invalid as edit should fix all issues with question. Bad title as well as bad tags.

Comment: They should be made synonyms. Equally we edit to improve the quality of the resource this site offers to home brewers, to educate and push forward the craft. Correcting things like this to be accurate and prevent the perpetuation of the usage of the incorrect term is important.

Comment: The edited questions are not about infections as beer can't become infected.